# In Bash, why is PROMPT_COMMAND set to something invisible?

Tags: bash, prompt, escape-characters, terminal-emulator

On RHEL6 and CentOS 6, `/etc/bashrc` sets `PROMPT_COMMAND` here:

```
case $TERM in
xterm*)
    if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
        PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
    else
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\007"'
    fi
    ;;
screen)
    if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
        PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
    else
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033_${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\033\\"'
    fi
```

All of these options, as far as I know, are printed invisibly. What is the use of this?

I know that `PROMPT_COMMAND` is to be executed before display the prompt (`PS1` usually). I do not understand why echoing something that is not visible is of any use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\033` is the octal code for the `Esc` (Escape) character, which is a good hint that the echoed strings in your `PROMPT_COMMAND` are terminal control sequences.  Both sequences in your examples look like they set the terminal title to `user@host:pwd`.

The first case, `xterm*` sets the window name and icon title.  For a detailed explanation, look at the list of [xterm control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) and scroll down until you find *OSC P s; P t; ST* under *Operating System Controls* (OSC is `ESC ]` and ST is `ESC \`).

The second case is for the `screen` terminal emulator, and in the list of [screen control sequences](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Control-Sequences), it explains that `ESC _` [sets screen's hardstatus](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Hardstatus) (simply put, that's the title of the screen window).