# Doubt on the value of PS1 environment variable

Tags: bash, prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is $debian_chroot in .bashrc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/what-is-debian-chroot-in-bashrc)
>   [In Bash, why is PROMPT_COMMAND set to something invisible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27692/in-bash-why-is-prompt-command-set-to-something-invisible)

I logged into my computer from a normal user and executed the following command:

```
pratheep@pratheep-laptop:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

I know that if I keep the value of `PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '` then also it will display the same.

I want to know what the extra thing in front i.e.
`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` is for?

Comment: [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/what-is-debian-chroot-in-bashrc) previously asked question might be of some help

Comment: [this](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/ps1/) Bash PS1 "Cheat Sheet" will help explain the rest of the prefix.
And, of course, The [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html)

Comment: The `debian_chroot` part is explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/what-is-debian-chroot-in-bashrc)

Comment: And the `\[\e]0; ... \a\]` part is explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27692/in-bash-why-is-prompt-command-set-to-something-invisible/).